# What is causing my code to not know which value I want to remove from local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm building a js web app that allows the user to add to a list of good habits and remove them as he/she wishes. Everyday, the app will then randomly select one for the user to do.

I have built all of the functionality for the app but I'm having trouble implementing local storage. When the user adds to the list of habits they are saved to local storage. Where I'm having trouble is when the user removes a habit from the list, the corresponding habit isn't removed from the local storage. It seems to remove a few habits from the local storage but not necessarily the one that the user clicks on.

Here is some of the code:

```
class Goodhabit {
    constructor(goodHabit) {
        this.goodHabit = goodHabit;
    }
}

class UI {
    addGoodHabit(goodhabit, callback) {
        const goodHabitList = document.getElementById('good-habit-list');

        // Create tr element
        const goodHabitRow = document.createElement('tr');

        // Insert html
        goodHabitRow.innerHTML = `
            <td class="good-habit">${goodhabit.goodHabit}</td>
            <td class="remove" id="remove">&#10005;</td>
        `;

        // Add row to list
        goodHabitList.appendChild(goodHabitRow);

        if(callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    removeGoodHabit(target, callback) {
        if(target.id === 'remove') {
            target.parentElement.remove();

            callback();
        }
    }
}

class Store {
    static getGoodHabits() {
        let goodhabitsls;
        if(localStorage.getItem('goodhabitsls') === null) {
            goodhabitsls = [];
        }   else {
            goodhabitsls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('goodhabitsls'));
        }

        return goodhabitsls
    }

    static displayGoodHabits() {
        const goodhabitsls = Store.getGoodHabits()

        goodhabitsls.forEach(function(goodhabit) {
            // Instantiate ui
            const ui = new UI;

            // Add good habit to ui
            ui.addGoodHabit(goodhabit)
        })
    }

    static addGoodHabitToLs(goodhabit) {
        const goodhabitsls = Store.getGoodHabits()

        goodhabitsls.push(goodhabit);

        localStorage.setItem('goodhabitsls', JSON.stringify(goodhabitsls));
    }

    static removeGoodHabitFromLs(habit) {
        const goodhabitsls = Store.getGoodHabits()

        goodhabitsls.forEach(function(goodhabit, index) {

            if(goodhabit = habit) {
                goodhabitsls.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('goodhabitsls', JSON.stringify(goodhabitsls));
    }
}

// Event Listener For Adding A Good Habit
document.getElementById('button-good-habit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Get form value
    const goodHabit = document.getElementById('good-habit-input').value;

    // Instantiate good habit
    const goodhabit = new Goodhabit(goodHabit);

    // Instantiate UI
    const ui = new UI();

    // Validate
    if(goodHabit === '') {
        // Code that displays warning
    }   else {
        // add good habit to list
        ui.addGoodHabit(goodhabit, goodHabitsNode);

        // add to ls
        Store.addGoodHabitToLs(goodhabit)

        // clear fields
        ui.clearFields();
    }
});

// Event Listener For Removing A Good Habit
document.getElementById('good-habit-list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    // Instantiate UI
    const ui = new UI();

    // Remove good habit from list
    ui.removeGoodHabit(e.target, goodHabitsNode);

    // Remove from ls
    Store.removeGoodHabitFromLs(e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
            if(goodhabit = habit) {
```

Use two equal signs `==` for comparison. Right now you're assigning `goodhabit` in your `forEach` instead of checking its value, so every iteration will splice another element out.

Edit:

As discussed in comments, the comparison wasn't working either because `goodhabitsls` is an array of *objects* and not strings.

The solution is to compare the property of the object with the parameter, and not the object itself:

```js
            if(goodhabit.goodHabit == habit) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! originally I used `===` and then `==` however, when I do this nothing is removed from the local storage.

Comment: @BoJack well, reassigning the parameter certainly is not a way to fix that. If your condition is never true, the `habit` getting passed in must not be right. You can try debugging this with a `console.log` or `alert(habit)` outside the loop.

Comment: After the forEach, if I console.log(goodhabit) I get {goodHabit: "aaa"} and if I console.log(habit) I just get aaa. I think this may have something to do with it as one is an object and the other is just text?

Comment: Sorry, reassigning the parameter was a rookie mistake by me!

Comment: @BoJack checking again, it looks like the list you're stuffing in localStorage is of good habit objects, not strings. So checking `goodhabit == habit`, where `habit` is a string and `goodhabit` is an *object*, is simply doomed to fail. Perhaps you might try `if(goodhabit.goodHabit == habit)`?

Comment: We have a solution! Thanks for the help